# Python logger- Selenium

Tags: python, error-logging

I'm doing an automation project which in in i want to record the results into a log file, I creacted a function that create the log file and write in it the messeges.
I dont get why this log file function does'nt work.
P.S, The test in the example runs perfectly.

```
    def test10(self):
    log=User(self.driver)
    log.LogIn('By1zx','Cb12')
    log.LogOut()
    logFile("INFO",10,True)

    #Logger creator
    def logFile(level,test,passedornot):
         lfile=r'C:\Users\97252\PycharmProjects\Automation\AutomationLogging\log.txt'
         logging.basicConfig(level= logging.INFO, filename="lfile",filemode="a")
         passtext="Failed"
         if(passedornot):passtext="Passed"
         if level == "INFO":logging.info(f'The test {test} {passtext}')
         if level == "ERROR":logging.error(f'The test {test} {passtext}')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed inefficiency in the code and a minor bug as well.

1. The bug is, filename=lfile. No double quotes required. You are referring variable not the string "lfile"

```
logging.basicConfig(level= logging.INFO, filename=lfile,filemode="a")
```

2. Every time you call logFile function, it will try to open file_pointer to append logs to log file. This would be overhead for the OS, if you use logFile function more frequently. The best approach for this is, [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler). Its worth looking into this library. Please comment if you have any questions on this library.

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: Which approach you tried and it didn't work? Did you use RotatingHandler above or you fixed filename variable?